Similar regression table with modelsummary as fixest with etable()
With fixest one can use etable() to produce regression tables of the form
library(fixest)
library(modelsummary)

data("trade")

lm1 <- feols(log(Euros) ~ log(dist_km), trade)
lm2 <- feols(log(Euros) ~ log(dist_km) | Origin + Destination + Product + Year, trade)

etable(lm1, lm2)

                               lm1                lm2
Dependent Var.:         log(Euros)         log(Euros)
                                                     
Constant         28.32*** (0.1696)                   
log(dist_km)    -1.910*** (0.0240) -2.170*** (0.1543)
Fixed-Effects:  ------------------ ------------------
Origin                          No                Yes
Destination                     No                Yes
Product                         No                Yes
Year                            No                Yes
_______________ __________________ __________________
S.E. type                      IID         by: Origin
Observations                38,325             38,325
R2                         0.14169            0.70558
Within R2                       --            0.21932
---
Signif. codes: 0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

whre we have yes/no for the fixed effects.
I would like to do something similar in modelsummary but by default I get
msummary(list(lm1, lm2), output = "markdown")

+-----------------+----------+------------+
|                 | (1)      | (2)        |
+=================+==========+============+
| (Intercept)     | 28.322   |            |
+-----------------+----------+------------+
|                 | (0.170)  |            |
+-----------------+----------+------------+
| log(dist_km)    | -1.910   | -2.170     |
+-----------------+----------+------------+
|                 | (0.024)  | (0.154)    |
+-----------------+----------+------------+
| Num.Obs.        | 38325    | 38325      |
+-----------------+----------+------------+
| R2              | 0.142    | 0.706      |
+-----------------+----------+------------+
| R2 Adj.         | 0.142    | 0.705      |
+-----------------+----------+------------+
| R2 Within       |          | 0.219      |
+-----------------+----------+------------+
| R2 Within Adj.  |          | 0.219      |
+-----------------+----------+------------+
| AIC             | 192375.0 | 151481.1   |
+-----------------+----------+------------+
| BIC             | 192392.1 | 151977.2   |
+-----------------+----------+------------+
| RMSE            | 2.98     | 1.74       |
+-----------------+----------+------------+
| Std.Errors      | IID      | by: Origin |
+-----------------+----------+------------+
| FE: Product     |          | X          |
+-----------------+----------+------------+
| FE: Year        |          | X          |
+-----------------+----------+------------+
| FE: Origin      |          | X          |
+-----------------+----------+------------+
| FE: Destination |          | X          |
+-----------------+----------+------------+

with only X for fixed effects when they are in the model. Could one do something similar with msummary?

You can use the glance_custom.fixest() mechanism: https://modelsummary.com/vignettes/modelsummary_extension.html#modifying-information-tidy_custom-and-glance_custom

Do you know if there is a way to extract information from multiple models at once? So far I have this but I think it gets applied model wise?
glance_custom.fixest <- function(x, ...) {   out <- tibble::tibble(.rows = 1)   for (n in insight::find_predictors(x)$cluster) {     out[[paste(tools::toTitleCase(n), "Fixed Effects")]] <- "Yes"   }   return(out) }
Because one model can have fixed effects and the other not and that one would get skipped then, since nsight::find_predictors(x)$cluster is NULL.

You don't need to extract information from multiple models at once. glance_custom() is applied once for every model, and that's what you want. Your function can simply include an if/else to return "No" whenfind_predictions() returns NULL.
